# How to shuffle element key in a std::map?

Tags: c++, stdvector, shuffle, stdmap

I am looking for a way to shuffle a std::map in C++.
I have a std::map with key as integers and value as struct and i want to shuffle the keys.
I tried to use std::random_shuffle, but it doesn't compile. So i created a temp vector, i populated this vector, shuffle it and use it to swap in the map.

This is how i currently do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>
#include <ctime>  
#include <cstdlib>

std::vector<int> temp_vec_registration;
int myrandom(int i) { return std::rand()%i; }

struct CRegInfo
{
    bool success;
    int num_order;
    int type;

    CRegInfo(bool succ, int num, int type)
        : success(succ), num_order(num), type(type)
        {}
};

typedef std::map<int, CRegInfo> RegInfo;
RegInfo register_chars;

int main()
{
    std::srand(unsigned(std::time(0)));

    temp_vec_registration.clear();
    register_chars.clear();

    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
        temp_vec_registration.push_back(i);

    std::random_shuffle(temp_vec_registration.begin(), temp_vec_registration.end(), myrandom);

    for (std::vector<int>::iterator it1=temp_vec_registration.begin(); it1!=temp_vec_registration.end(); ++it1)
        register_chars.insert(RegInfo::value_type(*it1, CRegInfo(false, 0, 0)));

    for (auto it2 = register_chars.begin(); it2 != register_chars.end(); ++it2)
            std::cout << it2->first << "\t";
}
```

But it doesn't work, the vector has random number, but the map always has the same numbers in key. (0, 1, 2, 3.. 10).

Comment: And the purpose behind this is?

Comment: std::map is an ordered container -  shuffling it doesn't make sense.

Comment: You can't change the"order" of a map. You could change the order that you read it. Use the shuffled vector as the keys to read the map.

Comment: Is the use of unordered_map prohibited?

Comment: @P.W You can't shuffle an `unordered_map` either.

Comment: @Sneftel: But can't we insert into an unordered_map after shuffling, as done here?

Comment: @P.W Sure, but the shuffling won't have any effect, any more than it does with `std::map`. (Well, it will have a *small* effect in the event of hash collisions, but that's it.)

Comment: I think what you want is `std::vector<std::pair<int,int>>` and not `map` or `unordered_map`.  A `std::map` is always sorted by key value, and a `std::unordered_map` depends on the hash of the key, thus these are the wrong tools for whatever job you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @P.W `std::unordered_map` is a hash table, so the order that the elements are iterated over is determined by the hashes, not the order that they were inserted in. The name of the container is kind of misleading, as it's not just a vector of the elements in some random order.

Comment: @FeiXiang The order of the elements in a hash table is determined by *both* hash values and insertion/deletion history. For example, if the unordered map contains two elements that happen to hash to the same bucket, their order in the map will depend on which one was inserted first. The unordered map is "unordered" in the order doesn't depend on contents only.

Comment: @user4815162342 Yes, the order of the elements does depend on the insertion order, but only when hash collisions happen. This isn't useful for what the OP is trying to do.

Answer (score -4):

Hmm, while this is technically possible with some additional hacking, but with naive approach—`std::map` is an ordered storage, i.e. it maintains ordering among its keys, which is its primary feature, for the price of logarithmic complexities of simple operations.

`std::unordered::map`, as its name suggests, does not give such guarantees so you might try luck doing the same with `unordered_map`... If you simply want to iterate over map items in an indeterminate order, well, use your shuffled vector for it.

Comment: `unordered_map` absolutely orders its items, just not in a semantically meaningful way. But there will generally be clear patterns to the order of items when iterating through an `unordered_map`.

Comment: And you can, of course, cite the paragraph of the Standard where it is guaranteed.

Comment: Huh? The standard delegates the choice of hash function to the implementation.

Comment: Of course `std::unordered_map` orders its elements in some way. How else do you get `O(1)` average lookups?

Comment: @FeiXiang To be fair, it would be *possible* to design an `unordered_map` implementation where iteration was in order of insertion, even though it wasn't bucketed like that. (There wouldn't be much reason to do so, though, and you couldn't reuse the structure for `unordered_multimap`.)